# Remove ...} trailing brace indentation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, clang-format

When I run clang-format 4.0 on (Javascript)

```
const board = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    board[i]        = [];
    board[i].length = 10;
    board[i].fill(0);
}

const P1 = 1;
```

It turns into

```
const board = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    board[i]        = [];
    board[i].length = 10;
    board[i].fill(0);
    }

const P1 = 1;
```

**EDIT**: This seems to be a problem with the statement after the trailing indent:
if I comment out the last statement, it remains unindented.

**How can I keep the trailing brace unindented?**

I'm using Sublime Text 3's Clang Format package, but that shouldn't change anything. My format configuration file:

```
{
    // All these settings have been taken from the clang-format manual, 
    // and can be customised form within Sublime Text settings files.
    // Please note, the defaults set below are completely random values.
    // Take a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
    // For examples.

    // The style used for all options not specifically set in the configuration.
    // Possible "values":
    //     LLVM 
    //     Google 
    //     Chromium 
    //     Mozilla 
    //     WebKit 
    "BasedOnStyle": "LLVM",

    "JavaScriptQuotes": "Double",
    // The extra indent or outdent of access modifiers, e.g. "public":.    
//  "AccessModifierOffset": 2,

    // If true, horizontally aligns arguments after an open bracket.
    // This applies to round brackets (parentheses), angle brackets and square brackets.
    // This will result in formattings like:
    // Possible values:

    // BAS_Align (in configuration: Align) Align parameters on the open bracket,
    //  e.g.:
    // someLongFunction(argument1,
    //                  argument2);
    //                  
    // BAS_DontAlign (in configuration: DontAlign) Don’t align, instead use 
    // ContinuationIndentWidth, e.g.:
    // someLongFunction(argument1,
    //     argument2);
    //     
    // BAS_AlwaysBreak (in configuration: AlwaysBreak) Always break after an 
    // open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line, e.g.:
    // someLongFunction(
    //     argument1, argument2);
//  "AlignAfterOpenBracket": true,

    // If true, aligns consecutive assignments.
    // This will align the assignment operators of consecutive lines.
    // This will result in formattings like:
    //     int aaaa = 12;
    //     int b    = 23;
    //     int ccc  = 23;
 "AlignConsecutiveAssignments": true,

    // If true, aligns consecutive declarations.
    // This will align the declaration names of consecutive lines. This will result in formattings like
    // int         aaaa = 12;
    // float       b = 23;
    // std::string ccc = 23;
// "AlignConsecutiveDeclarations": true,

    // If true, aligns escaped newlines as far left as possible. Otherwise puts
    // them into the right-most column.
 // "AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft": true,

    // If true, horizontally align operands of binary and ternary expressions.
// "AlignOperands": true,   

    // If true, aligns trailing comments.
 "AlignTrailingComments": true,

    // Allow putting all parameters of a function declaration onto the next line
    // even if BinPackParameters is false.
//  "AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine": true,

    // Allows contracting simple braced statements to a single line.
    // E.g., this allows if (a) { return; } to be put on a single line.
 "AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine": false,

    // If true, short case labels will be contracted to a single line.
//  "AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine": true,

    // Dependent on the value, int f() { return 0; } can be put on a single
    // line.
    // Possible values:
    //     SFS_None   (in "configuration": None) Never merge functions into a
    //     single line.    
    //     SFS_Empty (in configuration: Empty) Only merge empty functions.
    //     SFS_Inline (in "configuration": Inline) Only merge functions defined
    //     inside a class.
    //     SFS_All    (in "configuration": All) Merge all functions fitting on a
    //     single line.
 "AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine": "None",

    // If true, if (a) return; can be put on a single line.
//  "AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine": false,

    // If true, while (true) continue; can be put on a single line.
//  "AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine": true,

    // The function definition return type breaking style to use.
    // Possible values:
    //     DRTBS_None     (in configuration: None) Break after return type automatically.
    //     PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine is taken into account.
    //     DRTBS_All      (in configuration: All) Always break after the return type.
    //     DRTBS_TopLevel (in configuration: TopLevel) Always break after the return types
    //     of top level functions.
//  "AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType": "None",

    // If true, always break before multiline string literals.
    // This flag is mean to make cases where there are multiple multiline 
    // strings in a file look more consistent. Thus, it will only take effect 
    // if wrapping the string at that point leads to it being indented 
    // ContinuationIndentWidth spaces from the start of the line.
//  "AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings": true,

    // If true, always break after the template<...> of a template declaration.
//  "AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations": true,

    // If false, a function call’s arguments will either be all on the same line
    // or will have one line each.
//  "BinPackArguments": true,

    // If false, a function call’s or function definition’s parameters will
    // either all be on the same line or will have one line each.
//  "BinPackParameters": true,

    // Control of individual brace wrapping cases.
    // If BreakBeforeBraces is set to custom, use this to specify how each 
    // individual brace case should be handled. Otherwise, this is ignored.
    // Nested configuration flags:    
    // bool AfterClass Wrap class definitions.
    // bool AfterControlStatement Wrap control statements (if/for/while/switch/..).
    // bool AfterEnum Wrap enum definitions.
    // bool AfterFunction Wrap function definitions.
    // bool AfterNamespace Wrap namespace definitions.
    // bool AfterObjCDeclaration Wrap ObjC definitions (@autoreleasepool, interfaces, ..).
    // bool AfterStruct Wrap struct definitions.
    // bool AfterUnion Wrap union definitions.
    // bool BeforeCatch Wrap before catch.
    // bool BeforeElse Wrap before else.
    // bool IndentBraces Indent the wrapped braces themselves.
// "BraceWrapping": "IndentBraces",

    // Break after each annotation on a field in Java files.
// "BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations": true,

    // The way to wrap binary operators.
    // Possible values:
    // BOS_None (in configuration: None) Break after operators.
    // BOS_NonAssignment (in configuration: NonAssignment) Break before operators that aren’t assignments.
    // BOS_All (in configuration: All) Break before operators.
//  "BreakBeforeBinaryOperators": "None",

    // The brace breaking style to use.
    // Possible "values":
    // BS_Attach (in "configuration": Attach) Always attach braces to
    // surrounding context.
    // BS_Linux (in "configuration": Linux) Like Attach, but break before braces
    // on function, namespace and class definitions.
    // BS_Mozilla (in configuration: Mozilla) Like Attach, but break before 
    // braces on enum, function, and record definitions.
    // BS_Stroustrup (in "configuration": Stroustrup) Like Attach, but break
    // before function definitions.
    // BS_Allman (in "configuration": Allman) Always break before braces. 
    // BS_GNU (in "configuration": GNU) Always break before braces and add an extra
    // level of indentation to braces of control statements, not to those of
    // class, function or other definitions.
    // BS_WebKit (in configuration: WebKit) Like Attach, but break before functions.
    // BS_Custom (in configuration: Custom) Configure each individual brace in 
    // BraceWrapping.
 // "BreakBeforeBraces": "Attach",

    // If true, ternary operators will be placed after line breaks.
//  "BreakBeforeTernaryOperators": true,

    // Always break constructor initializers before commas and align the commas
    // with the colon.
//  "BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma": true,

    // The column limit. A column limit of 0 means that there is no column
    // limit. In this case, clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking
    // decisions within statements unless they contradict other rules.
 "ColumnLimit": 100,

    // A regular expression that describes comments with special meaning, which
    // should not be split into lines or otherwise changed.
    // "CommentPragmas": "",

    // If the constructor initializers don’t fit on a line, put each initializer
    // on its own line.
//  "ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine": true,

    // The number of characters to use for indentation of constructor
    // initializer lists.
//  "ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth": 2,

    // Indent width for line continuations.
//  "ContinuationIndentWidth": 2,

    // If true, format braced lists as best suited for C++11 braced lists.
    // Important "differences": - No spaces inside the braced list. - No line
    // break before the closing brace. - Indentation with the continuation
    // indent, not with the block indent. Fundamentally, C++11 braced lists are
    // formatted exactly like function calls would be formatted in their place.
    // If the braced list follows a name (e.g. a type or variable name), clang-
    // format formats as if the {} were the parentheses of a function call with
    // that name. If there is no name, a zero-length name is assumed.
//  "Cpp11BracedListStyle": true,

    // If true, analyze the formatted file for the most common alignment of 
    // & and *. PointerAlignment is then used only as fallback.
//  "DerivePointerAlignment": true,

    // Disables formatting completely.
//  "DisableFormat": false,

    // If true, clang-format detects whether function calls and definitions are
    // formatted with one parameter per line. Each call can be bin-packed, one-
    // per-line or inconclusive. If it is inconclusive, e.g. completely on one
    // line, but a decision needs to be made, clang-format analyzes whether
    // there are other bin-packed cases in the input file and act accordingly.
    // "NOTE": This is an experimental flag, that might go away or be renamed. Do
    // not use this in config files, etc. Use at your own risk.
//  "ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking": true,

    // A vector of macros that should be interpreted as foreach loops instead of
    // as function calls. These are expected to be macros of the "form":
    // FOREACH(<variable-declaration>, ...)
    // <loop-body>
    // In the .clang-format configuration file, this can be configured like:
    // ForEachMacros: ['RANGES_FOR', 'FOREACH']
    // For example: BOOST_FOREACH.
// "ForEachMacros": "['RANGES_FOR', 'FOREACH']" 

    // Regular expressions denoting the different #include categories used for 
    // ordering #includes.
    // These regular expressions are matched against the filename of an include
    // (including the <> or “”) in order. The value belonging to the first 
    // matching regular expression is assigned and #includes are sorted first 
    // according to increasing category number and then alphabetically within 
    // each category.
    // If none of the regular expressions match, UINT_MAX is assigned as 
    // category. The main header for a source file automatically gets 
    // category 0, so that it is kept at the beginning of the 
    // #includes (http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#include-style).
    // To configure this in the .clang-format file, use:
    // IncludeCategories:
    //   - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    //     Priority:        2
    //   - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|isl|json)/)'
    //     Priority:        3
    //   - Regex:           '.\*'
    //     Priority:        1
// "IncludeCategories": "UINT_MAX"

    // Indent case labels one level from the switch statement. When false, use
    // the same indentation level as for the switch statement. Switch statement
    // body is always indented one level more than case labels.
//  "IndentCaseLabels": true,

    // If true, indent when breaking function declarations which are not also
    // definitions after the type.
//  "IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType": true,

    // The number of columns to use for indentation.
 "IndentWidth": 4,

    // Indent if a function definition or declaration is wrapped after the type.
//  "IndentWrappedFunctionNames": true,

    // If true, empty lines at the start of blocks are kept.
// "KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks": true,

    // Language, this format style is targeted at. Possible "values": LK_None
    // (in "configuration": None) Do not use. LK_Cpp (in "configuration": Cpp)
    // Should be used for C, C++, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++. LK_JavaScript (in
    // "configuration": JavaScript) Should be used for JavaScript. LK_Proto (in
    // "configuration": Proto) Should be used for Protocol Buffers
    // ("https"://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). 
 "Language": "JavaScript",

    // A regular expression matching macros that start a block.
//  MacroBlockBegin: "*_MACRO_START"

    // A regular expression matching macros that end a block.
//  MacroBlockEnd: "*_MACRO_END",

    // The maximum number of consecutive empty lines to keep.
//  "MaxEmptyLinesToKeep": 2,

    // The indentation used for namespaces.
    // Possible "values":
    // NI_None (in "configuration": None) Don’t indent in namespaces.
    // NI_Inner (in "configuration": Inner) Indent only in inner namespaces
    // (nested in other namespaces).    
    // NI_All (in "configuration": All) Indent in all namespaces.
//  "NamespaceIndentation": "Inner",

    // The number of characters to use for indentation of ObjC blocks.
//  "ObjCBlockIndentWidth": 4,

    // Add a space after @property in Objective-C, i.e. use @property (readonly)
    // instead of @property(readonly).    
//  "ObjCSpaceAfterProperty": false,

    // Add a space in front of an Objective-C protocol list, i.e. use Foo
    // <Protocol> instead of Foo<Protocol>.    
//  "ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList": false,

    // The penalty for breaking a function call after “call(”.
//  "PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter": 0,

    // The penalty for each line break introduced inside a comment.
//  "PenaltyBreakComment": 0,

    // The penalty for breaking before the first <<.
//  "PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess": 0,

    // The penalty for each line break introduced inside a string literal.
//  "PenaltyBreakString": 0,

    // The penalty for each character outside of the column limit.
//  "PenaltyExcessCharacter": 0,

    // Penalty for putting the return type of a function onto its own line.
//  "PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine": 0,

    // Pointer and reference alignment style.
    // Possible values:
    //     PAS_Left   (in configuration: Left) Align pointer to the left.
    //     PAS_Right  (in configuration: Right) Align pointer to the right.
    //     PAS_Middle (in configuration: Middle) Align pointer in the middle.
//  "PointerAlignment": "PAS_Left",

    // If true, a space may be inserted after C style casts.
// "SpaceAfterCStyleCast": true,

    // If false, spaces will be removed before assignment operators.
//  "SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators": true,

    // Defines in which cases to put a space before opening parentheses.
    // Possible "values":
    // SBPO_Never (in "configuration": Never) Never put a space before opening
    // parentheses.
    // SBPO_ControlStatements (in "configuration": ControlStatements) Put a
    // space before opening parentheses only after control statement keywords
    // (for/if/while...).
    // SBPO_Always (in "configuration": Always) Always put a space before
    // opening parentheses, except when it’s prohibited by the syntax rules (in
    // function- like macro definitions) or when determined by other style rules
    // (after unary operators, opening parentheses, etc.)    
//  "SpaceBeforeParens": "ControlStatements",

    // If true, spaces may be inserted into ‘()’.
//  "SpaceInEmptyParentheses": true,

    // The number of spaces before trailing line comments (//-comments). This
    // does not affect trailing block comments (/**/-comments) as those commonly
    // have different usage patterns and a number of special cases.
//  "SpacesBeforeTrailingComments": 2,

    // If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘<’ and before ‘>’ in template
    // argument lists
//  "SpacesInAngles": true,

    // If true, spaces may be inserted into C style casts.
//  "SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses": true,

    // If true, spaces are inserted inside container literals (e.g. ObjC and
    // Javascript array and dict literals).    
//  "SpacesInContainerLiterals": true,

    // If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘(‘ and before ‘)’.
//  "SpacesInParentheses": true,

    // If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘[‘ and before ‘]’.
//  "SpacesInSquareBrackets": true,

    // Format compatible with this standard, e.g. use A<A<int> > instead of
    // A<A<int>> for LS_Cpp03. Possible "values":
    // LS_Cpp03 (in "configuration": Cpp03) Use C++03-compatible syntax.
    // LS_Cpp11 (in "configuration": Cpp11) Use features of C++11 (e.g.
    // A<A<int>> instead of A<A<int> >).    
    // LS_Auto (in "configuration": Auto) Automatic detection based on the input.
 // "Standard": "Cpp03",

    // The number of columns used for tab stops.
 "TabWidth": 4,

    // The way to use tab characters in the resulting file.
    // Possible "values":
    // UT_Never (in "configuration": Never) Never use tab. UT_ForIndentation (in
    // "configuration": ForIndentation) Use tabs only for indentation. UT_Always
    // (in "configuration": Always) Use tabs whenever we need to fill whitespace
    // that spans at least from one tab stop to the next one.
//  "UseTab": "Never"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This config seems to work for me

```
{"Language": "JavaScript",
    "TabWidth": 2,
    "UseTab": "ForIndentation",
    "AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine": true,
    "AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine": true,
    "AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine": true,
    "AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine": true,
    "AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine": true,
    "AlignConsecutiveAssignments": true,
    "BreakBeforeTernaryOperators": false,
    "ColumnLimit": 200,
    "IndentCaseLabels": true,
    "JavaScriptQuotes": "Single",
    "JavaScriptWrapImports": true,
    "KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks": true,
    "MaxEmptyLinesToKeep": 1,
    "NamespaceIndentation": "All",
    "SpaceBeforeParens": "ControlStatements",
    "SpaceInEmptyParentheses": false,
    "SpacesInAngles": false,
    "SpacesInContainerLiterals": false,
    "SpacesInParentheses": true}
```

Clang-format 5.0